# WPF Binding to Text property Of a TextBlock inside Selected TabItem of a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I know normally we can use this codes to bind **`Selected Tab Header Text`** and show selected tab:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2" />
</TabControl>

<Lable Content="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```

But how can i bind when i have this codes:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl">
    <TabItem>
         <TabItem.Header>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image Source="/Images/a.png" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Tab1" />
              </StackPanel>
         </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
         <TabItem.Header>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image Source="/Images/b.png" />
                  <TextBlock Text="Tab2" />
              </StackPanel>
         </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>

<Lable Content="{Binding ??????????? "/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning direct content to header you can make use of HeaderTemplate.
Refer below code.

```
 <TabControl Name="MyTabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Images/a.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Images/b.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>                   
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyTabControl, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```